# Identify and Update Duplicates in Array with Index Value in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array which may or may not include duplicates, but no nil or "" values.

```
array = ["Ballerina", "Lagoon", "Black", "Space", "Golden", "Lagoon"]
```

This is really the closest I've gotten to solving the problem, but the problem here is that I don't know the duplicates, so its not really valid:

```
array.each_with_index.map {|value, index| array[index] == "Lagoon" ? index : ""}.uniq
```

What I'm looking to return is for any duplicates in the array to concatenate the index value onto the end of the array value. So the end result would be:

```
array = ["Ballerina", "Lagoon 1", "Black", "Space", "Golden", "Lagoon 5"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) method to store a hash of total counts by value.

```rb
array = ["Ballerina", "Lagoon", "Black", "Space", "Golden", "Lagoon"]

# Generates hash for faster lookup
# {"Ballerina"=>1, "Lagoon"=>2, "Black"=>1, "Space"=>1, "Golden"=>1}
array_tally = array.tally

new_array = array.map.with_index do |value, index| 
    value_duplicated = array_tally[value] > 1
    
    if value_duplicated 
        "#{value} #{index}"
    else
       value 
    end
end

puts new_array.inspect
# output: ["Ballerina", "Lagoon 1", "Black", "Space", "Golden", "Lagoon 5"]
```

Comment: You might want to use `counts = array.tally` and check via `counts[value] > 1` to avoid traversing the whole array again and again to count each value.

Comment: Also, `.each_with_index.map` can be shortened to `.map.with_index`.

Comment: The "Alternative" is obviously far superior to your original answer so why don't you simply remove (and make no reference to) your original answer? I suggest that after defining `array` your answer begin, "The first step is to use [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) to store a hash of total counts by value.". When giving answers on SO think of writing an article or book that may require several edits, some possibly suggested by reviewers. If desired, you can give credit to reviewers by thanking them in a comment, as you have done.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, very much appreciate the tip.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
array = %w[Ballerina Lagoon Black Space Golden Lagoon]
```

Code

```
# create a hash of element counts

counts = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, counts| counts[element] += 1 }
# iterate through array and append index to duplicates
array.each_with_index do |element, index|
  if counts[element] > 1
    array[index] = "#{element} #{index}"
  end
end

p array
```

Output

```
#=> ["Ballerina", "Lagoon 1", "Black", "Space", "Golden", "Lagoon 5"]
```

Comment: `counts = array.tally` instead of your `array.each_with_object...`

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
arr = %w[Ballerina Lagoon Black Space Golden Lagoon]

cnt=arr.tally
arr2=arr.map.with_index{|e, i| cnt[e]>1 ? "#{e} #{i}" : e }

p arr2
# ["Ballerina", "Lagoon 1", "Black", "Space", "Golden", "Lagoon 5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intended for cases where the array is large and the number of duplicates is relatively small, in that the calculations suggested require only a single pass through the array.

Note that I do not claim it should necessarily be faster than methods whose first step employs the method [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), merely that it requires only a single pass through the array.

---

Suppose the array were as follows.

```
arr = ["Ballerina", "Space", "Lagoon", "Black", "Space", "Golden",
       "Lagoon", "Space"]
```

---

We first construct an array `indices` comprised  of indices of `arr` for which the `arr[i]` is to be modified in the required manner for each element `i` of `indices`.

```
indices = arr.each_with_index.
              with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(s,i),h|
                h[s] << i
              end.
              values.
              select { |a| a.size > 1 }.
              flatten
  #=> [1, 4, 7, 2, 6]
```

We then modify a copy of `arr` as required by iterating through `indices`.

```
indices.each_with_object(arr.dup) { |i,a| a[i] = "%s_%i" % [a[i], i] }
  #=> ["Ballerina", "Space_1", "Lagoon_2", "Black", "Space_4", "Golden",
  #    "Lagoon_6", "Space_7"]
```

---

By examining the source code for [Kernel#dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) one finds--unsurprisingly--that the method (implemented in C) copies a block of memory, and therefore does not constitute a second enumeration of the elements of `arr`.

---

The steps in computing `indices` are as follows.

```
h = arr.each_with_index.
        with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(s,i),h|
          h[s] << i
        end
  #=> {"Ballerina"=>[0], "Space"=>[1, 4, 7], "Lagoon"=>[2, 6],
       "Black"=>[3], "Golden"=>[5]}
```

```
a = h.values
  #=> [[0], [1, 4, 7], [2, 6], [3], [5]]
```

```
b = a.select { |a| a.size > 1 }
  #=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 6]]
```

```
b.flatten
  #=> [1, 4, 7, 2, 6]
```